# How to hide WooCommerce product title and short description to non logged in users?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using this code for hiding short description to logged out users but it does not work - it shows the message asking user to login but it still shows the short description.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'add_text_before_short_description_for_guests' );
function add_text_before_short_description_for_guests( $description ) {
    // Only for guest users
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $description = '<p>' . sprintf( __( "To check if this item qualifies for a discount %s an account."), '<a href="my-account link goes here"><u><strong>' . __("Log In or Create") . '</strong></u></a>' ) . '</p>' . $description;
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Format your code properly please so its easy to copy & paste for testing otherwise you might get downvotes and no help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$description` is shown because you concatenated it is your condition in

```
$description = '

' . sprintf( __( "To check if this item qualifies for a discount %s an account."), '' . __("Log In or Create") . '' ) . '
' . $description;
```

Does the below code helps ?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'add_text_before_short_description_for_guests' );
function add_text_before_short_description_for_guests( $description ) {
    // Only for guest users
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $description = sprintf( __( "To check if this item qualifies for a discount %s an account.", 'your_textdomain' ), '' . __( "Log In or Create", 'your_textdomain' )  );
    }

    return $description;
}
```

Do not forget to add your own or your theme (I don't know) text-domain to translate your work easily.

Comment: Thank you Sebastien that worked, much appreciated